# Avoid "Application Downloaded From The Internet" warning

Tags: macos, electron

I have written an app using electron and signed it.

I have confirmed I have signed it properly with the `codesign -dvvv` command:

```
Executable=/Volumes/MyApp/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
Identifier=com.example.my-app
Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=285 flags=0x0(none) hashes=3+3 location=embedded
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha1=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
CandidateCDHash sha256=exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Hash choices=sha1,sha256
CDHash=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Signature size=8925
Authority=Developer ID Application: Example, LLC (XXXXXXXXX)
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Timestamp=May 24, 2017, 4:30:26 PM
Info.plist entries=21
TeamIdentifier=XXXXXXXXXX
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=13 files=10
Internal requirements count=1 size=192
```

Yet, when my colleague downloads it from the internet for testing he receives this warning:

```
"MyApp" is an application downloaded from the Internet.  Are you sure you want to open it?
```

This is despite selecting "Mac App Store and identified developers" from "Security & Privacy" screen in settings.

Based on this description of Gatekeeper:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491

I would not expect to get that warning.

What can I change in how I build or distribute the app such that user will not receive that warning?  Our users are not tech savvy at at all so any warning message makes our phones ring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [article you linked about Gatekeeper](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491), if the app wasn't signed correctly, the warning would be different - "[MyApp] is from an unidentified developer" or "[MyApp] is damaged and can't be opened".

So the fact that you're getting "[MyApp] is an application downloaded from the Internet" is normal, and shows your app is correctly signed.

What you're seeing is the same warning the user will get downloading *any* application from the internet. For example, if you download Google Chrome, you will see the same message:

[image]

So your users should be used to seeing the message any time they download something outside of the Mac App Store.

To remove the warning, they would need to disable Gatekeeper entirely on their systems. There are instructions for doing that in [this blog post](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2017/04/20/fix-application-from-internet-gatekeeper/).

Comment: I actually believe you based on experience, but it seems to conflict with the "and identified developers" setting in Gatekeeper.  Why have that setting if one still gets a warning?

Comment: If Gatekeeper blocks an application from running, you don't get the Open option at all. With apps from identified developers *allowed* to run, you get the message in the screenshot - which allows you to run the app.